# Moving a robot in rviz

Tags: simulation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I would like to move the robot in rviz, from left to right, from front to back, etc. I understand that rviz is linked to a reference frame, so this does not look easy.

Is there a way to do this in a clean way?

I can still create 2 orthogonal and planar prismatics joints, but the robot model needs to be modify.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91086/moving-a-robot-in-rviz/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You just need to write a node that publishes a transform from some virtual link (e.g. "world") to your robot (e.g. "base_link"), and set the fixed frame in RViz to "world". If you need interaction, take a look at Interactive Markers.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on 2013-10-16**:
Thx for your answer. Could you tell me a little bit more about this transform publisher? Is it related to TF? TF seems to be designed to convert coordinates between frames, not to move them. I may be wrong since a huge piece of software.

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-10-16**:
I'm talking about tf, which is designed to handle moving coordinate frames. See the tutorials for further explanation: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials